# Is it a risk to disable joomla session handler

Tags: php, session, joomla

I want to disable session handler for guests in my joomla 3.7 site because

1. The site does not have login option front end
2. The host is already overloaded. Suspended the account twice in a month.
3. Mysql crashed several times.

So, please tell me which process is the best to disable session for guest (viewers). Also, if it is safe or not.
Thanks in advance.